# What is the primary phase?

Tags: discussion, election

Would it be possible to get more information on what the Primary phase entails, please?

The Nomination phase looks pretty self-explanatory, and I assume Election phase is about the community voting.

I'm vaguely aware there's a Primary phase in American elections (only because of '24'), but no idea what happens during it... Other than heroic rescues by insomniacs, obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the bar on the right-hand side of the election page:

> In the primary phase, all nominees advance to preliminary community
>   voting. Any community member with 150 reputation may vote in the
>   primary.
>
> There is no commenting in this phase, only one up or down vote per
>   candidate. The candidate vote scores are all public. Initial voting
>   should provide a rough sense of which candidates are most electable.
>
> All candidates are displayed in random order.
>
> The primary is not binding; nominees may withdraw at their discretion
>   at any point during the nomination phase.
>
> After 4 days, the top 10 candidates based on primary vote score
>   proceed onward to the election phase.

Comment: How bizarre. My right-hand bar is all about the nomination phase. All I have about the Primary is *"After 8 days, the top 30 nominees, ordered by reputation, advance to the primary phase. However, if there are 10 candidates or less, we skip directly to the election phase."* Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Oh, wait. I have to click that big "Primary" button... Now I feel daft.